# Flash message isn't shown in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, flash-message

My code:

Controller:

```
public function PostTest(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect('home')->with('status', 'Test ');
    }
```

Blade:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

But my template doesn't show the message.

I using laravel 5.5.40.

Comment: Looks fine, do you have any debug techniques you've deployed?

Comment: That *should* work; how are you calling `PostTest`? Via a `<form>` with `submit` or as an `AJAX` request? And is that `.blade.php` snippet actually included on the view file returned via the `home` route?

Comment: I call PostTest via a form with submit.

Comment: With this code I tried in laravel 5.3 & 5.6 work fine.

Comment: What does route callback for `home` do?

Comment: try `@if ($message = Session::get('status'))`  and then print `{{ $message }}`, i think when you  use `session('status')` in condition it clear the session

Comment: Thank @rkj. I tried, but it not work.

Comment: Thank @Nima, my full code display below.

Answer (score 1):

Thank all.
I resolved.

In Kernel.php, before I added :

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

I resolved error by removing 2 lines of code:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

Comment: do you know... if we added these lines, after that how we can get the session variable value?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace you code in the view with the following:

```
   @if(Session::has('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    {{ Session::get('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif
```

hope you got your answer

Comment: I think, the project error. With that code, I tried in other project work fine. But i don't know how to find error or repare in my project.

Comment: @user3447410  change your redirect method to: return redirect()->route('home')->with('status','Done');

Comment: @user3447410 Pleasure